# Return online users curl

Tags: php, curl

With this code can return the online users only on localhost. When sending to webhost crashes, even seeking the token code example in the second call. It only works with the second parameter tokem generated on site page source code. How to run this script from the webhost?

```
if (!function_exists('getHistats')) {
    function getHistats($sid = 0, $cc = '') {

        if (empty($sid) || empty($cc))
            return 'error';

        $url    = 'http://www.histats.com/viewstats/HST_GET_SUMMARY.php';
        $result = '';

        $ualist = array(
            'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.23 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/11.0.688.0 Chrome/11.0.688.0 Safari/534.23',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.14) Gecko/20110221 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.14 GTB7.1',
            'Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.01',
            'Midori/0.2.2 (X11; Linux i686; U; en-us) WebKit/531.2+',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1150.1 Iron/20.0.1150.1 Safari/536.11'
        );

        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {

            $http_headers                 = array();
            $http_headers[]               = 'Host: www.histats.com';
            $http_headers[]               = 'Referer: www.histats.com/viewstats/?sid='. $sid .'&act=2&f=1';
            $http_headers[]               = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';

            $opts                         = array();
            $opts[CURLOPT_URL]            = $url;
            $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER]     = $http_headers;
            $opts[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 5;
            $opts[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT]        = 10;
            $opts[CURLOPT_USERAGENT]      = $ualist[rand(0, count($ualist) - 1)];
            $opts[CURLOPT_HEADER]         = FALSE;
            $opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = TRUE;
            $opts[CURLOPT_POST]           = 1;
            $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]     = 'AR_REQ[sid]='. $sid .'&AR_REQ[CC]='. $cc .'&dbg=1';

            # Initialize PHP/CURL handle
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
            # Create return array
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

        } elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
            $result = file_get_contents($url);
        }


        if (empty($result) || ($result == 'error=11') || ($result == 'err:1'))
            return 'error';

        $obj = json_decode($result);

        return isset($obj->livearray->livesummary->cur_online) ? $obj->livearray->livesummary->cur_online : 0;
    }
}

$html = file_get_contents('http://histats.com/viewstats/?sid=3041076&act=2&f=1');

preg_match("/OBJ_summary.sockTOKEN = '(.*?)'/i", $html, $match);

echo 'Online: '. getHistats('3041076', 'bjh1NStBTVZyMFJzRENTODFHTHNQamJyV0FvY2l4TGRNSk5FczQyYnR3dERlaUhWczJZNUtWQk5lU2p6STlyRTZCQXZUd2t6MWJzS3Z2cWs2d1g4aXc9PQ==');
echo '<br />';
echo 'Token: '. $match[1];
echo '<br />';
echo 'Online: '. getHistats('3041076', $match[1]);
```

Comment: Nodejs is more suitable and will give you real time updates for this type events...

Comment: webserver crashes means.. blank page ? or 500 http code ? Check server logs etc.. , php error logs etc.